# TapKey failed to start foregroundScan

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, core-bluetooth, tapkey

I use tapkey sdk to open locks in my Flutter App, the app was working fine I was able to open locks when all the sudden I started to received this error on iOS (bluetooth permissions are granted):

`[CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid`

and

`[general] NetTpkyMcBleBleScannerImpl: failed to start foregroundScan: TapkeyMobileLib.TKMAsyncError`

I am so what confused because I am not sure if this like permission problem or tapkey sdk.

my AppDelegat.swift

```
 let tapKey = TapKey()

   methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
            (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult)  -> Void in
            switch call.method {
            case "login":
                
                let blueStart =  tapKey.TKMBleLockScanner.startForegroundScan()
                blueStart
                
                let  map : Dictionary =  call.arguments as! [String: String]
                
                let token = map["access_token"]
                let lockID = map["lock_id"]
                
                let userID =   tapKey.login(accessToken: token!)
                
                userID.continueOnUi{ (uID)  -> Void in
                    if(uID != nil) {
                        tapKey.padlock(userID: uID!, lockID: lockID!).continueOnUi { (lock) -> Void in
                            if(lock == "Lock is now open") {
                                result(lock)
                                blueStart.close()
                            } else {
                                tapKey.padlock(userID: uID!, lockID: lockID!).continueOnUi { (lock) -> Void in
                                    if(lock == "Lock is now open") {
                                        result(lock)
                                        blueStart.close()
                                    } else {
                                        tapKey.padlock(userID: uID!, lockID: lockID!).continueOnUi { (lock) -> Void in
                                            if(lock == "Lock is now open") {
                                                result(lock)
                                                blueStart.close()
                                            } else {
                                                result("Try again 1")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }.catchOnUi { TKMAsyncError in
                            print(TKMAsyncError)
                            blueStart.close()
                            result("Try again")
                        }
                    }     else {
                        result("TapKey Account Error")
                    }
                    
                    
                }.catchOnUi { TKMAsyncError in
                    print(TKMAsyncError)
                    result("TapKey Account Error")
                }
                
                
                
            default: result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
                
            }
        })
```

my TapKey.swift

```
import TapkeyMobileLib
import UIKit
import Flutter

// @UIApplicationMain
@objc class TapKey:  UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate  {
    
    var TKMServiceFactory: TKMServiceFactory!
    var TKMBleLockScanner: TKMBleLockScanner!
    override init() {
        
        
        self.TKMServiceFactory = TKMServiceFactoryBuilder()
            .build()
        
        self.TKMBleLockScanner = TKMServiceFactory.bleLockScanner
    }



    
    func login(accessToken: String ) -> TKMPromise<String>{
        
        
        
        let ct = TKMCancellationTokens.None
        
       return TKMServiceFactory.userManager.logInAsync(accessToken: accessToken, cancellationToken: ct)
        
        
    }

    func padlock(userID: String, lockID: String) -> TKMPromise<String> {
        
        let  result = TKMPromiseSource<String>()


    
            let sFS =  self.TKMBleLockScanner.startForegroundScan()
              
              
              let ct = TKMCancellationTokens.None

              let nearbyLocks = self.TKMBleLockScanner.locks
              
              if(nearbyLocks.isEmpty) {
                  result.setResult("No Locks nearby")
              } else {
                  
//                  let finalLock = nearbyLocks.values.first(where: {$0.physicalLockId == lockID})
                  let finalLock = nearbyLocks.first(where: {$0.value.physicalLockId == lockID})
                  
                  if(finalLock != nil) {
                      TKMServiceFactory.bleLockCommunicator.executeCommandAsync(bluetoothAddress: (finalLock?.value.bluetoothAddress)!, physicalLockId: finalLock?.value.physicalLockId, commandFunc:{
                          tlcpConnection -> TKMPromise<TKMCommandResult> in

                                                      let triggerLockCommand = TKMDefaultTriggerLockCommandBuilder()
                                                          .build()

                                                      // Pass the TLCP connection to the command execution facade
                          return self.TKMServiceFactory.commandExecutionFacade.executeStandardCommandAsync(tlcpConnection, command: triggerLockCommand, cancellationToken: ct)
                                                
                      }, cancellationToken: ct).continueOnUi({ commandResult in
                          let code: TKMCommandResult.TKMCommandResultCode = commandResult?.code ??
                                  TKMCommandResult.TKMCommandResultCode.technicalError

                          switch code {
                          case TKMCommandResult.TKMCommandResultCode.ok:
                              sFS.close()
                            _ =  self.TKMServiceFactory.userManager.logOutAsync(userId: userID, cancellationToken: ct)
                              result.setResult("Lock is now open")
                              return true
                          default:
                              result.setResult("Try again")
                              return false
                          }
                      }).catchOnUi({ (_: TKMAsyncError) -> Bool in
                          result.setResult("Try again")
                          return false
                      })
                  } else {
                      result.setResult("Lock doesn't match the bike")
                  }
                  
           
                  
              }
            




        return result.promise

    }
    
}
```

I' have double checked my iOS bluetooth premissions

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the ForgroundScanning twice which cause this issue. Additionally the scanning will only stopped when the unlock was successful.

1. in AppDelegat after login
2. In TapKey.swift after padlock

Scanning will only be stopped after TKMCommandResult.TKMCommandResultCode.ok.

Ensure that the scan is only once when required, and stopped when not required anymore. E.g. user moves away from the view. (During the unlock process the scanner must be running).

Additional you should not logout the user after unlock. The user session should be kept open as long your user is logged in in your app. Otherwise the user needs to be online during unlock and the unlock process will take longer, as the key has to be fetched in time.